# Check domain of another computer on the network

Tags: batch-file

I have two PC's, `pcA` and `pcB`.  I need to run a batch file on `pcA` to check if `pcB` is on the correct Domain (EEP202) If if it is, it should return PASS if not it should return FAIL.

I am not too good with networking, but I am guessing that I could first ping `pcB`.  If it does not pass then its definitely not on the correct domain.

If it does pass then I assume you can pull the domain from the ping?

Any help would be great!

Comment: When you say "domain" do you mean the Active Directory kind, the DNS kind, or something else? For DNS, do you mean whether it has the correct search domain? Is EEP202 a course number? Are there course notes you could link us to?

Comment: well by domain, i am not 100% sure. I have a troubleshooting guide that I am trying to make into a batch file. Thus we just have to run the program and it tells us where it fails.  The guide only says "Check to make sure the panel(pcB) is on the correct domain. So i asssume its the one you select when you login. pretty much checking to make sure its not in local mode.  EEP202 is just the domain we loginto when logging onto a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Windows domain, you can use nbtstat to query a computer's name, domain and some other properties:

```
nbtstat -A x.x.x.x
```

Here's a [link from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961857.aspx) with an explanation of the options and output format.

If you want the domain specifically, you can use:

```
nbtstat -A x.x.x.x | find "<00>" | find "GROUP"
```

Ping will not return what domain a computer is joined to.

You can get 0 or 1 for the domain eep202 with this single line:

```
nbtstat -A x.x.x.x | find "<00>" | find "GROUP" | find /c /i "eep202"
```

If you really want to only echo "pass" on success then you'll need to write a batch file. Let's call it verify_eep202.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('nbtstat -A %1 ^| find "<00>" ^| find "GROUP" ^| find /c /i "eep202"') do set found=%%a
if %found%==1 echo pass
```

You can then run `verify_eep202.bat x.x.x.x`

Comment: Ok this will return the text "EEP202 <00>  GROUP  Registered"  How can i hide this from showing, and test to make sure the group name is =  EEP202 ?

Comment: What did you want in the output? "pass" or "fail"?